# Is there a way to import Paragraphs with Feeds module (no code)?

Tags: feeds, paragraphs

Given a Content Type (a Node), which has a Paragraph field, which in turn has some fields on it, is there a way to import the Paragraph fields into the Content Type using Feeds (or some other method, but not involving coding)?

Example: 
The Content type Photograph includes a Paragraph field called 'Inscription' that has these fields:

field_inscription (text)
field_inscription_type (term reference)
field_inscription_location (term reference)

How do I import these three fields into the Paragraph field of a Photograph Content Type?

Note: There will be multiple instances of the Inscription field on some photographs.

I'm currently in Drupal 7, but would consider working in Drupal 8, if there's a solution that works in Drupal 8.

Comment: I don't think there is a working solution for this available at the moment. For the Field Collection module there has been a similar request: https://www.drupal.org/node/1063434. You could try to import the paragraphs with separate importers using the Feeds entity processor (https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_entity_processor).

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal 8 version of Paragraphs does support some basic Feeds integration with a "Target" (see the [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/paragraphs/tree/src/Feeds/Target/Paragraphs.php?h=8.x-1.x))

Alternatively you could write a Processor plugin that manually creates and associates the paragraphs contained within a node.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, in D7, you can have a try at [feeds_para_mapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_para_mapper)